# Subquery as string to new query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this working static query:

```
SELECT 
    companyname,
    companyid,
    incorporationcountryid,
    periodEndDate,
    filingdate,
    AVG(dataitemvalue) FILTER (WHERE menmonic = 'AT') as "AT",
    AVG(dataitemvalue) FILTER (WHERE menmonic = 'COGS') as "COGS"
FROM
    aaa3
GROUP BY 
    companyname, companyid,
    incorporationcountryid, periodEndDate, filingdate
ORDER BY 
    companyname, periodEndDate
```

Now, I'd like to incorporate all mnemonics, not just 'AT' and 'COGS' and adjust my query dynamically. I'm relatively new to SQL, but I managed to come up with this query, that gets me all unique mnemonics in my table and creates my desired query as a string:

```
SELECT 'SELECT companyname,companyid,incorporationcountryid,periodEndDate,filingdate,' 
|| STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT('AVG(dataitemvalue) FILTER (WHERE menmonic = "', menmonic,'") as "',menmonic,'"'),',') 
|| ' FROM aaa3 GROUP BY companyname, companyid, incorporationcountryid, periodEndDate, filingdate ORDER BY companyname, periodEndDate;'
as menmonic FROM aaa2;
```

[image]

Q: Can I turn this string into a query?

Comment: Yes, but how depends on what tool you are using.  psql, python, plpgsql, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a compact solution myself:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  menmonic_list text[];
  query text;
  menmonic_unique text;
BEGIN
  SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT menmonic) INTO menmonic_list
  FROM aaa3;

  query := 'SELECT companyname, companyid, incorporationcountryid, periodEndDate, filingdate';
  FOREACH menmonic_unique IN ARRAY menmonic_list
  LOOP
    query := query || ', AVG(dataitemvalue) FILTER (WHERE aaa3.menmonic = ''' || menmonic_unique || ''') AS "' || menmonic_unique || '"';
  END LOOP;
  query := query || ' FROM aaa3 GROUP BY companyname, companyid, incorporationcountryid, periodEndDate, filingdate ORDER BY companyname, periodEndDate';

  EXECUTE query;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first idea that comes up in mind would be to store your string into a text variable and then execute it as a dynamic query using `EXECUTE` (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)).

But then comes the issue : the query to be executed has a variable number of columns depending on the number of menmonics in table aaa2.

So the problem is a bit more tricky and one possible solution is to create dynamically a composite type `menmonic_list` corresponding to the list of menmonics and then to use the `jsonb_populate_record` and `jsonb_object_agg` standard functions :

Creating the composite type `menmonic_list` by trigger each time a row is inserted or updated or deleted from table aaa2 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aaa2_AFTER_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE ()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
  DECLARE
    str text ;
  BEGIN
    SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT quote_ident(menmonic) || ' numeric', ',') 
      INTO str
      FROM aaa2 ;
    DROP TYPE IF EXISTS menmonic_list ;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE menmonic_list AS (' || str || ')' ;
    RETURN NULL ;
  END ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER aaa2_AFTER AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF menmonic OR DELETE ON aaa2
  FOR EACH statement EXECUTE FUNCTION aaa2_AFTER_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE () ;
```

The final query is :

```
SELECT a.companyname,a.companyid,a.incorporationcountryid,a.periodEndDate,a.filingdate,
  (jsonb_populate_record(null :: menmonic_list, jsonb_object_agg(a.key, a.value))).*
FROM
( SELECT companyname,companyid,incorporationcountryid,periodEndDate,filingdate,
  menmonic AS key, AVG(dataitemvalue) AS value
  FROM aaa3 
  GROUP BY companyname, companyid, incorporationcountryid, periodEndDate, filingdate, menmonic
) AS a  
  GROUP BY a.companyname, a.companyid, a.incorporationcountryid, a.periodEndDate, a.filingdate
  ORDER BY a.companyname, a.periodEndDate;
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jX9Kyzn2)

Comment: Hi & thanks for your answer. Although it works in dbfiddle, when I run it in VSCode, I get a syntax error at or near "TRIGGER" for the line that starts with "CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER .."

Comment: I've never used VSCode, I even didn't know that one can test postgres code in VSCode, is it connected to a postgres database ?

Comment: Yes, you can download the extension, connect to your db, and then run queries.